# Using R, how to pivot/transform a dataset whose elements are the result of a function

Tags: r, pivot

I have the following toy dataset:

```
z <- c(2,2,3,3,3,4,2,2)
y <- c(6,6,6,5,4,6,6,5)
x <- c(1,1,2,3,5,4,4,3)
df <- cbind(x,y,z)
```

I would like to figure out how many times an element z appears with an element x for each element y. The resulting dataset should look like the following:

```
     y(4) y(5) y(6)
x(1)  0    0    2
x(2)  0    0    1 
x(3)  0    2    0
x(4)  0    0    2
x(5)  1    0    0
```

The solution needs to be scalable such that the number of elements in x,y, and z is irrelevant.

Comment: What role plays column `z` in your desired output?

Comment: Every instance where z exists for (Xn, Yn) is counted and summed in the table

Comment: You will get same result even you would delete `z` column, so I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired result is just a `table` of `x` and `y`.

```
> table(df[,"x"], df[,"y"])
#   
#    4 5 6
#  1 0 0 2
#  2 0 0 1
#  3 0 2 0
#  4 0 0 2
#  5 1 0 0
```

Maybe converting `df` to a `data.frame` might make more sense

```
> df <- data.frame(df)
> with(df, table(x, y))
#    y
# x   4 5 6
#   1 0 0 2
#   2 0 0 1
#   3 0 2 0
#   4 0 0 2
#   5 1 0 0
```

Comment: as.data.frame.matrix(with(df, table(x,y))) is exactly what I was look for. Thanks!